# Find recurring date nearest to today - C#

Tags: c#, datetime, recurring

Sounds like a homework? no it's not. I worked up the logic for this but not such a performant one when dates are span over years.
Basically here is how it should work,

```
StartDate: 1/1/2012

FinishDate: 1/10/2012 

RecurringInterval: 2 ( In days)
```

**Output would be:**

`1/6/2012` if Todays date (`Date.Now`) is `1/5/2012` ( Assuming format `MM/dd/yyyy`). Check would end when finish date is reached. If no dates match within given time period, today's Date must be returned. Dead simple but not a efficient one.

#### What is wrong with this?

```
if (!_isRecurring)
    return DateTime.UtcNow;
DateTime initialDate = _startDate;
DateTime finalDate = _finishDate;
int recurringDays = _recurringInteral;
/*
 * start Date + recurring interval falls between start date and finishdate then get its date
 */
do
{
    //add recurring day to start date
    initialDate = initialDate.AddDays(recurringDays);
    //check if it falls in between start days and end days
     if(initialDate  <= finalDate)
    break;            
} while (initialDate <= finalDate);
//return the first occurance of the recurring day
return initialDate;
```

Comment: How could the output be even for an odd start date 1/1 and an even interval of 2 days? I thought the acceptable dates would be 1/3, 1/5, 1/7, and 1/9, no?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A little arithmetic should save the day (pun intended):

```
var start = new DateTime(2012, 1, 1);
var end = new DateTime(2012, 10, 1);
var interval = 2; // days

var today = DateTime.Today;
var diff = (int)((today - start).TotalDays);
var mod = diff % interval;
var correction = TimeSpan.FromDays((mod > interval / 2 ? interval : 0) - mod);
var result = today + correction > end ? today : today + correction;
Console.Out.WriteLine("Result is: {0}", result);
```

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/6ChoK)**.

What this does is calculate how many days away from a "recurrence spot" today is (variable `mod`). This is obviously going to be a number >= 0 and < interval. If it's half the interval or less, it means the closest recurrence spot is earlier than today, in which case subtract `mod` days from today to find the spot. If it's greater than half the interval, it means that we need to add `interval - mod` days to find the spot (which is going to be in the future).

Comment: +1 worked pretty well for me. Does the calculations pretty well.

Comment: @Deeptechtons: Math always works. It's humans that make mistakes. ;-)

Comment: And i am a human so is all SO users . thanks again for clearing my mistake.

Comment: @Deeptechtons: Sure, including me. I didn't mean it like that.

Comment: me too, i was reassuring that i was human ( and i always use to think i write working code, i didn't wanted to mean that u were pin pointing my mistake :) lol )